# ROG STRIX G17 4060 Driver

Tags: drivers, 20.04, nvidia

Hi i have purchased ROG STRIX G17 with 4060 nvidia gpu, processor - AMD® Ryzen 9 7845hx with radeon graphics × 24. Installed Ubuntu 20.04 but many drivers are working even nvidia gpu isnt working. No audio No Wifi No bluetooth. My current kernel version is- **5.15.0-75-generic**
I have heared that switching from 20.04 to 22.04 can work but i can't switch as i have to ros noetic and it supports ubuntu 20 only :(
What to do how to install these any suggestions or help?

Comment: Try a newer version of Ubuntu, such as 22.04 LTS. If that does not work, try 23.04.

Comment: Actually im stuck to 20.04 because im using ros noetic and it only works on 20.04 i cant changes another distro

Comment: You may want to edit your question and add the information about the app you are using, how you installed it, and the current kernel of Ubuntu. Particularly if you are using HWE kernels for 20.04.

Comment: Done!! I have added kernel and all the info